# Mixing Android widget old & new themes

Tags: android, themes, android-edittext, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm starting my second Android app and find that I would like to mostly use HOLO dark theme for app.

EXCEPT for the EditTexts, I would prefer to use the old Gingerbread style ones (looking closer to iOS) with some rounded corner.

I'm a bit lost as to how I can achieve this. If anyone could drop some hints or links that would be HIGHLY appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Theme:

```
<style name="myTheme"  parent="android:Theme.Holo">
<item name="editTextStyle">@style/MyWidget.EditText</item>
</style>

<style name="MyWidget.EditText" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text</item>
</style>
```

Now you can get the referenced drawable from [Github](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/gingerbread/core/res/res)(from the Gingerbread branch of the framework)

Comment: Hey Ahmad, thanks for the info, let me try and see if this works for me before accepting the answer

Comment: when I add edit_text.xml i get errors regarding @drawable/textfield_default, @drawable/textfield_disabled, etc not being in my drawable folder, but I cant find these files on GitHub?

Comment: You'll have to search for them in the drawable-hdpi/mdpi/ldpi folders on github. E.g. https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/gingerbread/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/textfield_default.9.png

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, much appreciated. On a related question, is there 9-path generator so I can modify this puppies to have round corners?

Comment: Yes, in your android SDK -> tools -> draw9patch or online http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html