# I can't see all the border of the EditText

Tags: android, xml

I am new at Android and I downloaded some code for a login screen. I cannot see all the border and I only see half of it (the bottom of the edittext).  I think the reason is something about the configuration of the layout.
Can anyone help me out?

This is what it looks like:
[image]

Below I show you how I would like to have it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The difference there is based on the different styles of Android. The one you don't like is actually the new type of style that android is running with called Holo. It's a good idea unless you have to change to stick with this theme.

The other EditText is from an older version of android and in fact the EditText will change it's look just based on which android version you run it off.

For example, try making an emulator with android version 2.2 and you'll see the EditText look that you like, while i'm guessing this one you're running is android 4.0 or higher, so therefore has the Holo Theme.

If you really want to make it look like the old style android then have a look at this answer on how to do so: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14056519/161711)

Answer (score 0):

For creating custom dialog, you can try following.

**Step 1.**  Have a `dialog.xml` in your `res/layout/` folder, which can contain how you want your EditText box to look like. Something like following will draw a border around the `EditText`. You can also describe the colors of the border:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" /> 
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/> 
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="7dp" 
            android:right="10dp" android:bottom="7dp" /> 
    <corners android:radius="2dp" /> 
</shape>
```

**Step 2** Then in the XML of your edit Text you may define the `android:background` as that drawable XML file. Something like:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog"/>
```

This will give your EditText the look you want. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="myTheme"  parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/MyWidget.EditText</item>
</style>

<style name="MyWidget.EditText" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text</item>
</style>
```

You can use above code in your Theme style